# Criar uma tabela com dados iniciais no Django

Tags: python, django

Quero criar uma tabela com os nomes/tipos de um modelo, no caso, são documentos, tenho esse código do modelo

```
class Document(models.Model):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    process_owner = models.ForeignKey(Process, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
```

No caso, quero trocar o name por uma foreign key de uma tabela com todos os nomes já instanciados. Como faço para criar essa tabela já populada com Django?

Comment: Não entendi, vc quer que o nome seja um FK de uma tabela que contem os nomes? se for isso é só fazer da mesma forma que vc fez com  `process_owner`.

Comment: Sim, mas quero que essa tabela seja populada com dados iniciais e fixos, essa é a pergunta

Comment: Qual delas: a dos nomes ou a dos documentos? e de onde viriam esses dados?

Comment: Eu quero criar uma tabela com dados iniciais e fixos, ela vai conter o Id e o uma string do nome, e quero mudar o campo name pra uma foreign key dessa tabela, a questão é como criar a tabela já com dados, esses dados vão ser hardcoded

Comment: Não ha necessidade de "criar a tabela ja com os dados", crie a tabela normalmente e depois crie um comando para popula-la, simples.

Comment: Mas essa é a pergunta, como fazer isso? Não quero ter que abrir o postgres ou o django admin e colocar na mão todos os dados toda vez que eu instalar o app, deve haver uma maneira mais inteligente

Comment: Ok, vou responder com um exemplo

Comment: @Sidon Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode criar a tabela normalmente e então criar um comando para popula-la na hora que quiser, como vc disse (nos comentarios) que os dados serão "hardcoded", vou dar um exemplo bem "simplão" e "basicão", então é só vc adaptar.

Digamos que sua app Django se chame `core`, crie uma módulo chamado `management` e, dentro dele um outro chamado commands e então um arquivo chamado `initialdata.py`, a estrutura deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
core
├── __init__.py
├── management
│   ├── commands
│   │   ├── initialdata.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
```

Crie o comando dentro de `initialdata.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Create initial data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if User.objects.filter(Q(username='admin') & Q(is_superuser=1)):

            # Primeiro limpe a tabela
            Document.objects.all().delete()

            # Agora popule-a
            # Repita a linha abaixo para qtos registros vc precisar.
            Document.objects.create(field1 = value1,.... fieldN = valueN)
        else:
            print('Inclua um usuário superuser com o nome admin')
```

Ok, agora para colocar esses dados na tabela, faça na sua linha de comando:

```
python manage.py initialdata
```

Veja que, da forma que eu fiz, para usar o comando vc precisa, antes, criar um superusuario com o nome admin.

> Usando fixtures
>   A pratica comum na comunidade django, para dados iniciais é através de fixtures, para isso basta criar um diretorio chamado `fixtures` dentro de sua app e entao criar um json, assim o comando  manage.py loaddata fixturename, popula a(s) tabela(s), automaticamente, mas utilizando um comando fica mais flexivel pq vc pode ler outras tabelas (como é o seu caso) e/ou fazer outros processo antes de gravar na tabela alvo, se voce quiser experimentar com fixtures, veja [esse link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/howto/initial-data/)

**Consideração final:**
Hardcoded é dureza heim? sugiro criar um json e fazer um função para lêlo, dentro de `initialdata.py`

Comment: Como tô fazendo só o protótipo ainda, acho que com fixtures faz mais sentido, pq é mais simples, muito obrigado!